# Visual Studio 2015 and Entity Framework Migrations not working

Tags: c#, entity-framework, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, entity-framework-6

We are using Visual Studio 2015 Update 1 and Entity Framework 6.1.3. Also we are following the Code-First approach and are using Entity Framework Migrations to respond to schema changes. Since updating to Visual Studio 2015, some fellow developers can not add any Entity Framework Migrations. When executing 'Add-Migration', Entity Framework does not find any migrations in the project and asks you to turn on migrations.

Anyone experienced a similar issue and knows a solutions? Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Is there any previous migrations available? I mean, migrations done in previous setting is yet existing?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. By previous setting you mean with Visual Studio 2013? Everyone is working with Visual Studio 2015 Update 1. We are always creating a migration and everyone is doing get latest, since we experienced issues with multiple pending migrations created by different developers.

Comment: Do you have the right Default Project and StartUp Project selected? Can you copy the exact error you're getting?

Comment: The default project selected in the package manager console is the one with the migrations and the DbContext. The startup project is a different project, but referencing the one with DbContext. We are getting the following error message "no migrations configuration type was found in the assembly" - which is odd, since we selected the right default project.

Comment: Have you tried explicit parameters like -ContextProjectName <String> ? https://coding.abel.nu/2012/03/ef-migrations-command-reference/

Comment: A very good tip. We will try and give feedback, if it's working. Perhaps it's just a VS UI Bug...

Comment: I am afraid it did not work :-(

Answer (score 1):

We were able to determine the root cause and fix the issues.

Issues:

- Avoid having more than one classes derived from DbContext in an assembly
- We used the Nu-Get package EntityFrameworkWithHierarchyId, which is not just an extension, but a fork of the Entity Framework. When we replaced all dependencies to EntityFramework by EntityFrameworkWithHierarchyId, the issue disappeared. It properly occured by different install routines in the provided  PowerShell Scripts and the different Assemlblies